# While trade is open, check if middleBand is crossed below twice, if true trigger SL

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to check if the price is "crossing down" twice the middleBand :

```
longSLCondition = ta.crossover(close, middleBand ) and ta.crossover(close, middleBand )
```

Condition closes the trade but the wrong way :

[image: Example]

In the chart, you can see that the price closes a first time below the middleBand just after the trade was opened. Then he closes above the middleBand and the SL is triggered (red circle).

I would like the SL triggered when the price closes a second time below the middleBand (green circle) and not above.

Thanks for your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea was to trigger a stop loss if the price close twice below the middle band.

Here's the solution :

```
var int cross_count = 0 // Initialize the counter variable
if ta.crossunder(close, middleBand)
    cross_count := cross_count + 1 // Increment the counter if condition is met
```

```
// --- Long Entry | Close
if delayElapsed
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long)
    cross_count:=0 // Reset the counter after having entered the trade
```

```
f (cross_count >= 2 and strategy.position_size > 0) // Check if long trade and price crossed twice the middleBand 
    strategy.close('long', comment="SL Long")
```